# Make target to copy files

Tags: makefile

This seems simple, but it is eluding me. How can I create a single target to copy a list of files with different filenames?

I am trying to copy all the $(IMG) files in ../images/class to the current directory.

I have tried this:

```
CP := cp

IMGS := \
  A.png \
  A.tif \
  A.eps \
  B.png \
  B.tif \
  B.eps

SRC_IMG_DIR := ../images/class

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(IMGS): $$($(SRC_IMG_DIR)/$$@)
    $(CP) -f $^ $@
```

Comment: What about this isn't working exactly? What happens when you run `make`? ... Oh, I see.

Comment: Including specific detailed error, undesired results is **really** helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you're just confusing yourself trying to use secondary expansion in the first place.  This is a simple situation, so a simple application of a standard pattern rule will do the trick:

```
% : $(SRC_IMG_DIR)/%
        $(CP) -f $< $@
```

Secondary expansion is only need for more complicated / tricky problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are expanding one too many times.

You are taking `$(SRC_IMG_DIR)/$$@)` the `$(SRC_IMG_DIR)` bit is being expanded during the initial parsing phase and the `$$@` bit of which is being expanded during the secondary expansion mini-phase and **then** expanding that **result** again.

So assume you run `make A.png` the initial parse results in `A.png A.tif ...: $(../images/class/$@)`.

Target determination then occurs and `make` decides it needs to build `A.png` so it finds the `A.png` target and sees that it needs to expand `$(../images/class/$@)`, expands `$@` (which is `A.png`) and gets `$(../images/class/A.png)` and then expands `../images/class/A.png` *as a variable name* and ends up with an empty prerequisite and ends up running `cp -f  A.png`.

You don't want that last expansion so drop the wrapping `$(...)`:

```
$(IMGS): $(SRC_IMG_DIR)/$$@
```